# Multiple config files in Cypress 10?

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I am currently running my E2E tests in multiple environments. To achieve this, I have created a config file for each environment and passed the configFile value in the CLI. When upgrading, I realized Cypress 10.0.0 does not support multiple config files. Is there a way to achieve this in the latest version of Cypress?

Comment: You are mistaken - Cypress 10.0.0 does support multiple config files.

Answer (score 0):

The `--configFile` option does not seem to have changed

[Ref](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Specifying-an-Alternative-Config-File)

> **Specifying an Alternative Config File**
> In the Cypress CLI, you can change which config file Cypress will use with the --config-file flag.
>
> ```js
> cypress run --config-file tests/cypress.config.js
> ```

Did you have another use in mind?